# Xamarin GCM Component - Manifest Malformed

Tags: android, xamarin

I am developing an Android application with Xamarin.Android.

My application is running perfectly, but when I add `GCM` Component it gives the following error:

```
Android application is debugging.
The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).
Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.
```

If I remove the component then it works fine.

Here is the image for the error:

[image]

I have tried many solutions from Google, but nothing has helped.

How can I prevent this error from happening?

Comment: The error states - Manifest Malformed. Please [edit] your question to include the contents of your manifest.

Comment: In the future, please copy your code / errors into the text block. None of us want to read / test from an image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your package name does not start with an uppercase letter - from your screenshot, it looks like it does "**R**estaurantAPP".

This is a known issue with GCM itself and is not a bug in the Xamarin component: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37658